# Need help redirecting a txt file into 3 different array of structs of different sizes (number of elements in the struct)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is the txt file:

```
P 20.0 2.0 20.1 60.1
P 20.0 2.0 58.1 60.1
P 20.0 2.0 20.1 20.1
P 20.0 2.0 58.1 20.1
O 1.0 1.0
O 2.0 70.0
O 70.0 10.0
X 8.0 8.0
X 8.0 70.0
X 70.0 70.0
X 70.0 8.0
```

All structures starting with the same letter have to be in the same array. The code I'v been trying looks like this, but I know I'm way off. I feel as though I need to do something like "if struct has 5 elements" then store.

```
typedef struct {    
    char   id; 
    double trans_pow; 
    double sig_freq;
    double x_cord;
    double y_cord; 
    } WAP_t;


void wap_struct_reader(WAP_t waps[], int *counter) { 
    int i=0;       
    while(scanf("%c %lf %lf %lf %lf", &waps[i].id, &waps[i].trans_pow, 
            &waps[i].sig_freq, &waps[i].x_cord, &waps[i].y_cord)!=EOF) { 
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly and provide a code example that can be compiled and run.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show the definition of `WAP_t`. Also show us where and what these 3 arrays you mention are.

Comment: ill copy and paste everything, but its not even worth compiling yet as i dont undertand the concept of how to scan it in yet.

Comment: typedef struct { 
 
 char   id; 
 double trans_pow; 
 double sig_freq;
 double x_cord;
 double y_cord; 
} WAP_t;

Comment: @JackBarrett please [edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: so in that struct i want to save all the lines starting with P in the txt file above

Comment: So you need three `WAP_t` arrays, one for P, one for O and one for X. See my answer below.

Comment: and then subsequently in a new struct the ones starting O and X

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this:

```
void wap_struct_reader(WAP_t p_waps[], WAP_t o_waps[], WAP_t x_waps[], int *counter) {
  int pcount = 0, ocount = 0, xcount = 0;
  char id;
  double trans_pow, sig_freq, x_cord, y_cord;
  *counter = 0;
  while (scanf("%c %lf %lf %lf %lf", &id, &trans_pow, &sig_freq, &x_cord, &y_cord) != EOF) 
  {
    WAP_t *p;
    int i;
    switch (id)
    {
    case 'P': p = p_waps; i = pcount++;  break;
    case 'O': p = o_waps; i = ocount++;  break;
    case 'X': p = x_waps; i = xcount++;  break;
    default:
      // TODO: handle case line starts neither with P, O or X.
    }

    p[i].id = id;
    p[i].trans_pow;
    p[i].sig_freq;
    p[i].x_cord = x_cord;
    p[i].y_cord = y_cord;

    (*counter)++;
  }
}
```

P, O and X lines may be mixed in the input file, so this file is valid.

```
X 8.0 70.0
P 20.0 2.0 20.1 60.1
X 70.0 70.0
P 20.0 2.0 58.1 20.1
O 1.0 1.0
O 2.0 70.0
```

Call it like that:

```
WAP_t pwaps[10], owaps[10], xwaps[10];
int counter;

wap_struct_reader(pwaps, owaps, xwaps, &counter);
```

**Disclaimers:**

- There is no boundschecking whatsoever done here for brevity.
- You certainly need 3 counters, one for the P lines, one for O lines and one for X lines. I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @JackBarrett I guessed what the `WAP_t` struct was, so when you've answered to my comment, most of the answer had already been written.